# Cómo captar fechas desde una barra de búsqueda

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Buenas, tengo una barra de búsqueda en la parte superior de mi navbar para buscar coincidencias en mi base de datos. Concretamente, coincidencias con el **titulo**, la **fecha** y el **país** de las fotos que se hayan subido.

La **SELECT** que hago es la siguiente (la gestiono de forma dinámica, de ahí que la concatene):

```
 $sql .= " titulo LIKE '%$infoBusqueda%' OR fecha LIKE '%$infoBusqueda%' OR pais LIKE '%$infoBusqueda%'";
```

**PROBLEMA**:

Me encuentra coincidencias cuando hago búsquedas por título y país, pero **no encuentra cuando introduzco una fecha**, sea el formato que sea (Ej: 01/11/2017, 2017/11/01... etc).

¿Alguien me podría ayudar? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es mejor usar consultas parametrizadas, en vez de concatenar las variables directamente en la cadena SQL, para evitar este tipo de problemas y otros mas. Otra nota, no me parece correcto que tus filtros estén combinados con el operador `OR`. Dudo que produzca el resultado deseado.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. El caso es que también tengo un formulario de búsqueda avanzada con varios inputs, de ahí que las utilice de forma dinámica para controlar cuales se han seteado y cuales no. Por otro lado, por qué dices que el `OR` me puede dar problemas. Lo uso para buscar coincidencia en cualquiera de las columnas, no es así?

Comment: lo que sstan quiere decir, es que si busco el titulo A y el pais B, me va a traer cualquier cosa para titulo A, sin importar el pais, por el OR. Ademas un like para una fecha, suena muy raro. Deberia ser un campo de fecha, con lo cual deberia ser algo mas directo. Y tu consulta no es dinamica. no se porque piensas eso, si siempre busca en todos los campos.

Comment: Digo que es dinámica puesto que concateno unos criterios de búsqueda en función de los campos que se hayan rellenado. Mi razonamiento para poner un `OR` es que el valor de `$infoBusqueda` será igual a lo que introduzcan en la **barra de búsqueda**, que es donde está mi duda, independientemente del apartado búsqueda avanzada donde hay más inputs. Al ser una barra de búsqueda, buscas coindicencias dependiendo de lo que te hayan introducido no? Puede tener una coincidencia parcial con algún dato de la BD, quiero decir. Voy por mal camino? jajajaja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las bases de datos suelen manejar las fechas del tipo aaaa-mm-dd por lo que en el formato que lo estás utilizando no te va a servir. Podrías hacer uso del siguiente código:

```
try {
    DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $infoBusqueda);
    $fecha = $date->format('Y-m-d');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $fecha = $infoBusqueda;
}
$sql .= " titulo LIKE '%$infoBusqueda%' OR fecha LIKE '%$fecha%' OR pais LIKE '%$infoBusqueda%'";
```

Y por cierto es **altamente** recomendable que parametrices las sentencias, sino podrías ser víctima de un ataque de inyección SQL, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
$sql .= " titulo LIKE ? OR fecha LIKE ? OR pais LIKE ?";
$q = $dbc->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array('%$infoBusqueda%', '%$fecha%', '%$infoBusqueda%'));
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda!

Saludos!

Comment: Me convence tu respuesta, pero he encontrado otro inconveniente en mi caso: al revisar el dato que esta enviando el input, pone lo siguiente **01%2F11%2F2017** para la fecha 01/11/2017. No esta interpretando bien, o lo está haciendo con un juego de caracteres distinto. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Fijate que esté el html con el charset en UTF-8 (en Google aparece la sintaxis específica para hacerlo), luego, verifica que en el PHP no estés codificando la entrada en formato URI. El resto es debug, quizás abriendo otra pregunta con ese tema en paticular puedas recibir ayuda más acorde!

Answer (score 0):

Para tu respuesta hay dos posibles casos.

Si el **campo fecha** es de **tipo `DATETIME`**, en este caso tu consulta no será valida, ya que estas comparando una cadena con una fecha. El formato de la fecha, ademas debe ser `YYYY/MM/DD`, con lo que de alguna manera debes convertir la entrada del usuario a este formato.
Para usar las fechas la comparación debe realizarse con el operado `=` y en caso de querer filtrar por un rango de fechas, te aconsejo que uses la sentencia con un `BETWEEN fecha1 AND fecha2`

Si tu **campo fecha** es de **tipo `VARCHAR`**, si sería posible que uses la clausula `LIKE`, pero debes tener en cuenta que el formato es el de `YYYY/MM/DD`

Y por último como consejo, encierra cada una de las condiciones entre los simbolos '(' y ')', para que tengas mas claro como usar el operador `AND` y `OR`

Answer (score -1):

He encontrado una solución (dejo aquí la fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506930/how-to-query-datetime-field-using-only-date-in-sql-server)

Puedes usar un rango:

```
select * from test 
where date between '03/19/2014' and '03/19/2014 23:59:59'
```

o usa la función datediff():

```
select * from test 
where datediff(day, date, '03/19/2014') = 0
```

Espero que te funcione, un saludo!

Comment: Esta es una pregunta de PHP con MySQL. La respuesta que das es para SQL Server.

Comment: @sstan simplemente hay que introducir el código SQL en una variable de PHP y ejecutar la consulta...